# Warning: Application delegate received call to

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am implementing a local notification method but I recieved that warning

```
Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:withResponseInfo:completionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.
```

Here is my code in didfinishlaunchmethod

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {



        UIMutableUserNotificationAction *snooze=[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
        [snooze setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
        [snooze setTitle:@"Snooze"];
        [snooze setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
        [snooze setDestructive:NO];
        [snooze setAuthenticationRequired:YES];

        UIMutableUserNotificationAction *cancel=[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
        [cancel setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
        [cancel setTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [cancel setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
        [cancel setDestructive:NO];
        [cancel setAuthenticationRequired:YES];

        UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
        actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
        [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
        [actionCategory setActions:@[cancel, snooze]
                        forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

        NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];

        UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
        settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                     categories:categories];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

and here is code for completion handler

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
 {
    NSLog(@"called");
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionOneIdent]) {


        NSLog(@"You choose snooze");
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (localNotif == nil) return;

        NSDate *fireTime = [[NSDate date]   dateByAddingTimeInterval:900];

        localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Time to wake up";
        localNotif.repeatInterval=kCFCalendarUnitMinute;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionTwoIdent]) {

        NSLog(@"You choose cancel");
    }

        completionHandler();
}
```

But i am geeting same warning again and again.. please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an exit point in the handle function that does not call the `completionHandler()`

`if (localNotif == nil) return;`

Fix this and the error should go away.

```
if (localNotif != nil) {
        NSDate *fireTime = [[NSDate date]   dateByAddingTimeInterval:900];
        localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Time to wake up";
        localNotif.repeatInterval=kCFCalendarUnitMinute;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

Comment: Did you remove `if (localNotif == nil) return;` line?

Comment: yes, but solve that problem , It's working fine on device and not working on simulator. @Pardeep K Thanks

Comment: you mean local notifications not working on the simulator or are you still getting that warning in the simulator but not on the device?

Comment: yes, i am still getting warning on device but when i test it on device than its  working fine @Pardeep K

Comment: Hello to all, I am facing this issue in ionic-cordova project any suggestion ?